# Condition in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I just learn about numpy and array today and I am quite confused about something. I don’t get line 3 as I thought np.array() should have a list in the (). Can someone explain that line to me? And for line 5, I know it is comparing array x and y. But can someone explain to me how it works? And what does x[y] mean? Thank you so much.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array(x<4)
print(y)
print(x[y])
```

Answer (score 1):

What this code snippet does is *masking* the `x` array with a condition. `x[y]` is the masked array, which shows only the elements of `x` where `y` is True (in that case where `x < 4`).

`y = np.array(x < 4)` has an useless `np.array` call, as `x < 4` is already a numpy array. That being said, you can give many objects to `np.array()` such as lists, tuples, other arrays...

The whole thing should be simply:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(x[x < 4])
# [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Line three tells you the places in x where the value is less than four. You don't need the "np.array" constructor out front though - `y = x<4` will return you the same array.

Line five filters the x array, using the values in y that are 'True'. This is often referred to as a 'mask'.